# Revisit "Inequality between Frobenius and nuclear norm"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, nuclear-norm, matrix-norms

I am reading the following question:

[Inequality between Frobenius and nuclear norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397442/inequality-between-frobenius-and-nuclear-norm)

I know $$\|X\|_* = \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i(X)$$and $$\|X\|_F = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^r \sigma^2_i(X)\bigg)^{1/2}$$

I try to prove it by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality; however, I cannot see how to use C-S inequality to prove this. Could anyone please give me a small hint?  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy—Schwarz tells you that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^r a_i b_i \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^r b_i^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
Apply it with $a_i = 1$, $b_i = \sigma_i(X)$ (for $1\leq i\leq r$).